# File Chooser not opening in Android Lollipop on Oppo F1 & LG G2

Tags: android, webview, filechooser

I have one problem with Oppo F1 and LG G2 running Lollipop. On other devices running Lollipop, the problem does not appear

My Problem is that File Chooser doesn't show with the mentioned devices.

What I'm currently doing:

```
private WebView web;


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_event);


        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_addEvent);
        web.loadUrl(tempURL);

        startWebViewForLolipop();

}


 private void startWebViewForLolipop() {


    //CODING FOR LOLIPOP VERSION

    // Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
    // Called When opening a url or click on link
    // You can create external class extends with WebViewClient
    // Taking WebViewClient as inner class

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //If you will not use this method url links are open in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            // Check if Url contains ExternalLinks string in url
            // then open url in new browser
            // else all webview links will open in webview browser
            if (url.contains("google")) {

                // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                //Open links in new browser
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                // Here we can open new activity

                return true;

            } else {

                // Stay within this webview and load url
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        }


        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

            // if url contains string androidexample
            // Then show progress  Dialog
          /*  if (progressDialog == null *//*&& url.contains("androidexample")*//*
                    ) {

                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddEvent.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }*/
        }

        // Called when all page resources loaded
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            try {
                // Close progressDialog

                if (probressbar.isShown())
                    probressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });


    // You can create external class extends with WebChromeClient
    // Taking WebViewClient as inner class
    // we will define openFileChooser for select file from camera or sdcard

    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

            // Update message
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try {

                // Create ImgDir Folder at sdcard

                File imageStorageDir = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                        , "ImgDir");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {

                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();

                } else {

                    //Delete Old Content
                    if (imageStorageDir.isDirectory()) {

                        String[] children = imageStorageDir.list();
                        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                            new File(imageStorageDir, children[i]).delete();
                        }
                    }

                    imageStorageDir.delete();

                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();

                }

                // Create camera captured image file path and name
                File file = new File(
                        imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                + ".jpg");

                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

                // Camera capture image intent
                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");

                // Create file chooser intent
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

                // Set camera intent to file chooser
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                        , new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

                // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType,
                                    String capture) {

            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }


        // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a
        // console message informing what action to perform,
        // taking a photo or updating the file

        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {

            onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
            return true;
        }

        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
            Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message);

        }
    });   // End setWebChromeClient
/*

    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

           */
/* File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "ImgDir/addEvent");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create ImgDir/addEvent  Folder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");


            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);*//*

           */
/* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                try {
                    Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: when open file chooser failed
                }
            } else {*//*

                // Set up the take picture intent
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(AddEvent.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go

                    File photoFile = null;

                    try{

                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);


                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        Log.e("TAG", "Unable to create Image File", e);
                    }


                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                // Set up the intent to get an existing image
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image*/
/*");

                // Set up the intents for the Intent chooser
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);
           // }
            return true;
        }


    });
    */


}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;

            }

            Uri result = null;

            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;

                } else {

                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    //result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();

                    Log.d("TAG", "Image File Path : " + mCapturedImageURI);
                    String test = intent.toString();
                    if (intent == null) {

                        String temp  = decodeFile(mCapturedImageURI.getPath(), getImageName(mCapturedImageURI.getPath()));
                        result = Uri.parse("file:///"+temp);
                        //result = mCapturedImageURI;

                    } else {
                        if (test.equals("Intent {  }")) {
                            String temp  = decodeFile(mCapturedImageURI.getPath(), getImageName(mCapturedImageURI.getPath()));
                            result = Uri.parse("file:///"+temp);
                            //result = mCapturedImageURI;
                        } else {
                            String temp  = decodeFile(intent.getData().toString(), getImageName(intent.getData().toString()));
                            result = Uri.parse("file:///"+temp);

                            result = Uri.parse(decodeFile(intent.getData().toString(), getImageName(intent.getData().toString())));
                            //result = intent.getData();
                        }
                    }

                   /* // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    String test = intent.toString();
                    if (intent == null) {

                        result = mCapturedImageURI;
                    } else {
                        if (test.equals("Intent {  }")) {
                            result = mCapturedImageURI;
                        } else
                            result = intent.getData();
                    }*/
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }

    } else {

 /*       if (requestCode == 1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
            mFilePathCallback = null;
            return;
        } else {*/

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            //// TODO: 23/6/16 temporary comment this code
            /*if (requestCode != 1 || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                return;
            }*/

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }

            Uri result = null;

            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    //result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();

                    Log.d("TAG", "Image File Path : " + mCapturedImageURI);

                    if (intent == null) {

                        String temp  = decodeFile(mCapturedImageURI.getPath(), getImageName(mCapturedImageURI.getPath()));
                        result = Uri.parse("file:///"+temp);
                        //result = mCapturedImageURI;

                    } else {
                        String test = intent.toString();

                        if (test.equals("Intent {  }")) {
                            String temp  = decodeFile(mCapturedImageURI.getPath(), getImageName(mCapturedImageURI.getPath()));
                            result = Uri.parse("file:///"+temp);
                            //result = mCapturedImageURI;
                        } else {
                            String temp  = decodeFile(intent.getData().toString(), getImageName(intent.getData().toString()));
                            result = Uri.parse("file:///"+temp);

                            result = Uri.parse(decodeFile(intent.getData().toString(), getImageName(intent.getData().toString())));
                            //result = intent.getData();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

           /* Uri[] results = null;

            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (intent == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }

            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
            return;*/
            //  }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. And you are not the first one who happens this. Please Google.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion mate but i have search a lot before posting this question if you have any links than kindly give me.